# How do you add a counter numbering for a loop of a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing, ecmascript-6

My data looks like this

```
posts : {
    author1 : {
        "article1" : { },
        "article2" : { }
    },
    author2 : {
        "article1" : { },
        "article2" : { }
    }
```

I have a counter that loops through articles and numbers 
      `Object.keys().map((key)=>..` and then displays counter for each article `key + 1` etc. Works perfectly fine but now i want to display all authors and show all articles.

My UI looks like this

Author1

1. Article
2. Article

Author2

1. Article
2. Article

I want to change be like this

Author1

1. Article1
2. Article2

Author2

3. Article1
4. Article2

How do i make the second loop start from the end author1

Comment: Show your code in your question please

Comment: Just put the variable in the scope of the outer loop, not in the inner one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to iterate both properties and values of an object. Note, there are duplicate property names at code at Question

```js
const posts = {
  author1: {
    "article1": {a:1},
    "article2": {b:2}
  },
  author2: {
    "article1": {c:3},
    "article2": {d:4}
  }
}

for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(posts)) {
  console.log(`${key}:\n`);
  for (let [item, articles] of Object.entries(prop)) {
    console.log(`${item}:${JSON.stringify(articles)}\n`);      
  } 
}
```